# Laravel 5: Installing ide helper for Netbeans

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, laravel-5

Im trying to implement Laravel ide helper: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper .
Tried downloading gist, putting it in root folder of my project but it did not work. 
Also tried installing it with composer and adding `Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class` in the config/app.php file.
Both methods didnt work even when I restarted netbeans.

Using Ubuntu and Laravel 5.1.20

Anyone have idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing it with composer isn't enough, you still have to generate it with this command:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

Better yet add it as a `post-update-cmd` to composer.json:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
  "php artisan clear-compiled",
  "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
  "php artisan optimize"
]
```

(the other 2 should already be there)

Then whenever you run `composer update` it will automatically generate a new IDE helper file. Finally, don't forget to add `_ide_helper.php` to your .gitignore file

Comment: Accepted answer but unfortunatelly I cant vote you up cause I dont have 15 reputation yet